# #3. Write a program to find out the prime factors of a number. Example: prime factors of 56 - #2, 2, 2, 7

Tags: factors, prime-factoring

```
number=56
int(number)
c=[]

for i in range(2,number//2):
    if(number%i==0):
        c.append(i)
        number=number//i     
print(c)
```

In this program, after `number=number//i`, i (in the range) is changing and becoming 3 and that's the reason why the `print(c)` gives 4 in the result.

I want to loop this i in such a way it will start from 2 several times.

I've taken another variable and looped in but still gives 4 instead of 2 with 
`for i in range(2,number//2):`

Comment: Please read your question and try to revise it in a way, that person, who doesn't know the details of it can understand it. Also - you mean python, right? Please also mind the formatting.

Comment: the output is : [2, 4, 7]

Comment: replace the if by a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, as each prime factor can be needed several times, like in 8 = 2*2*2, you need to add a loop checking the modulo until it's no longer 0.
In your case, the best choice is a while loop, instead of the if, and no other syntax needs to be changed.
Note also that if you had been using a set instead of a list, by using `c=set()` and later `c.add(i)`, the result would still be wrong as elements in a set are unique...